# How to delete blank line at beginning of docx from officer

Tags: r, officer

I am using `officer` for `R` to create a a Word (docx) document. Here is the code:

```
library(officer)
library(magrittr)

my_docx = read_docx() %>% 
  # cursor_begin() %<>% 
  body_add_par("Hello here is a test sentence to see if there is a blank line above it.", style = "Normal") %>% 
  print(target = "test.docx")
```

It creates a docx document that has a blank line at the top above the sentence. It isn't spacing before the font style that is set in the Style of the font. I have uncommented `cursor_begin()` but the blank line remains. How can I get rid of this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There is a `pos` argument to `body_add_par` that I was missing and it can be set to `before` and that will adjust position of text in docx document...my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a paragraph, you need to use function `body_remove()`. See documentation here: https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/articles/word.html#remove-content

```
library(officer)
library(magrittr)

my_docx <- read_docx() %>% 
  cursor_begin() %>% body_remove() %>% 
  body_add_par("Hello here is a test sentence to see if there is a blank line above it.", 
               style = "Normal") %>% 
  print(target = "test.docx")
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't need to remove a paragraph since I was starting with a blank template...it was just the cursor position argument in the `body_add_par` that I had omitted which now seems silly as I did not fully read the documentation...and thanks for `officer`

Comment: Could you validate my solution? This answer your original question.